# Insert from combo box using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, combobox

I am populating a combo box from database, the problem is when I select an item from the combo box and try to save to another table in the database it picks the record ID column instead of the item itself.
this is the how am populating the combo box.

```
<label>State</label>
<select name="state" class="state" onChange="display(this.value)" width="142" style="width: 142px">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State --</option>
<?php
$query="select * from tbl_state";
$query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
                        {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>

  </select>
<div id="show_city" style="position: relative" height:5px;>
     <label>LGA</label>
      <select name="city" class="lga" width="142" style="width: 142px">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select LGA --</option>
       </select>
</div>
</p>
```

**Database connection**

```
$state              = $_POST['state'];
$city               = $_POST['city'];

$sql="INSERT INTO members (state, city)
VALUES ('$state', '$city')";
```

NB. am using javascript to populate the combo box.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I have two combo boxes that am populating dynamically from database with two tables, when I select items from "state" the "lga" combo box populates with a items from tbl_lga.
the problem here is that i am using these combo boxes in a form so what i want is to submit the form data including the selected  items from the two combo boxes to another table in my data base.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, only the field name along with its value will be sent. In your case, when the user select the state and press submit, the row id will be sent as you specify the row id at the option value tag.

Either you can use `<option value="<?= $row['state_name'] ?>"> ... </option>"` and then get the state name ini php directly:

```
    $state = $_POST['state'];
```

or leave the populating code as is now and get the state name by querying database using the record id.

```
    $state_id = intval($_POST['state']);
    $city_id  = intval($_POST['city']);

    $sql = "SELECT `state_name` FROM tbl_state WHERE id=$state_id";
    $query_result = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();

    $state = mysql_result($query_result, 0);
    echo $state;
```

*getcity.php*

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Mysql not connected');
mysql_select_db('thriftdb',$con) or die('DataBase not connected');

$state_id=$_REQUEST['state_id'];

$query="select * from lga where state_id='$state_id'";

?>
<label>LGA</label>
<select name="city" width="142" style="width: 142px">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select LGA --</option>
<?php
$query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['lga_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

database structure is as follows
'lga' table has...

```
lga_id --- state_id --- lga_name
```

'state' table has

```
state_id  --- state_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... I'm kinda lost though... tried using this but the fields returned blank...

Comment: @Crossyde which one do you use? The first one or the second?

Comment: i tried using both... on different occasions though

Comment: Ok @Syahmi it workded... thanks a grat deal.... I have another problem though, the city field is blank. I think its because am pulling from a different table from the "state" table... any clue as to how I can handle that.. once again, thanks.

Comment: @Crossyde, i only show the code for state. If you need to pull out data from city, you must query the database like how you query the state name from database.

Comment: Thank you @Syahmi for your response. the problem here is that the 'lga' table kinda depends on the state table because the city-combobox populates on selection of a state in the state combobox so it is kinda not possible for me to just query the 'lga' table directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How the 'lga' table looks like? Do you already have the code for populating city?

Comment: getcity.php

<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Mysql not connected');
mysql_select_db('thriftdb',$con) or die('DataBase not connected');

$state_id=$_REQUEST['state_id'];

$query="select * from lga where state_id='$state_id'";

?>
<label>LGA</label>
<select name="city" width="142" style="width: 142px">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select LGA --</option>
<?php
$query_result=mysql_query($query)or mysql_error();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['lga_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>

Comment: oops... let me post it below

Comment: What is 'id' refer to on your lga table? Where is 'state_id' on your table?

Comment: oh sorry state_id is the unique key present in both state and lga table respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When a form sends the selected item of a combo, it sends the value of the option selected, not the text. If you want to send the text, add a hidden input for every combo, then in the onclick event of the combos, call a function that populates the text to the hidden input.

```
selectState = function() {
    $('#hiddenInputField').val($("select[name='state'] option:selected").text());
}
```

Then in the server side you must get the value of the input hidden field instead of the select field.

Comment: Thanks for this method... although i tried  using it but dont seem to get it to work.